# Why are some commands not working in the terminal of Ubuntu on my Chromebook?

Tags: command-line, chromebook

I installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook following the guide [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/install-ubuntu-on-your-chromebook-using.html). I am still a beginner on using Ubuntu so all I could tell once it started is that it came almost "naked" (without several programs that usually come preloaded with Ubuntu). I tried opening the terminal and for example

```
sudo add-apt-repository
```

is not recognized. Several other commands are also not recognized. What is a good way to install all the programs like LibreOffice and a nicer terminal (the only thing I have right now is a terminal called XTerm) along with having all the commands like add-apt-repository that I usually use?

Comment: Even if you added launchpad PPA's you probably couldn't install software anyways since Launchpad only host 32 and 64 bit packages as far as I know (someone correct me if this isn't the cause). Usint ARM will sadly keep you from using many software you can use in a 32 and 64bit OS.

Comment: @xangua I am not using ARM. It's Intel.

Comment: Since you used crouton to install Ubntu in a Chromebook and mention the guide you used has the description "
Ubuntu on a Chromebook (ARM) in chroot using Crouton
", I guess you are.

Comment: Should I not use Crouton?

Comment: Did you follow either the To install Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity (2D) or To install Ubuntu 14.04 with Xfce option of the guide. Also, I don't have link but there was recently crouton change that allows you to run ubuntu out of a tab, so that way your still in Chrome

Comment: The one with Unity (2D). So far I can run Ubuntu out of a tab yes. What I am looking for is a way to install all the programs that usually come preloaded with Ubuntu

Comment: I think something went wrong during install. You may want to try this guide http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343. It says in there " Your desktop won't come with very many programs installed. You'll find that even a lot of default Ubuntu tools are left out, so you'll have to install them yourself using apt-get. If you're on an ARM-based Chromebook, not all apps will be compatible. Intel users will be much better off." so it sounds like you will need to manually install. Like another user pointed out, I think the guide you used was for arm,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add-apt-repository` is part of the package `software-properties-common`, therefore install the package first:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

To find other packages, use the [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), the preinstalled *Ubuntu Software Center* or the [Ubuntu app directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Good one!  Simple, elegant, correct!

Answer (score 0):

To access the chroot with crouton you need to type,

`sudo enter-chroot start (input your version here(xfce4 is what i have))`